# Associating Target Groups with Component Presentations?

Tags: componentpresentation, sdl-tridion

We added component presentation as follows

Component Presentation 1: Component 1 + CT 1 + Target group: Desktop
Component Presentation 2: Component 1 + CT 1 + Target group: Tablet
Component Presentation 3: Component 1 + CT 2 + Target group: Mobile

Clarification:Associating Target Groups with Component Presentations?

After publishing the page Only Component Presentation 1 displayed 3 times.

Component Presentation 1: Component 1 + CT 1 + Target group: Desktop
Component Presentation 2: Component 2 + CT 1 + Target group: Tablet
Component Presentation 3: Component 3 + CT 2 + Target group: Mobile

After Publishing the page for Desktop, Component Presentation 1 displayed.
When verified Tablet Component Presentation 2 displayed.
When verified Mobile Component Presentation 3 displayed.

How the Target group conditions works? Where can we see the conditions output similar to "

Comment: Which version are you using? Which publishing model?

Comment: We are using 2013 SP1 and We are using Dynamic Component Presentation Model (DCP Model) and Template output Format is REL

Comment: Using Modular Templating?

Comment: Yes we are using Modular Templating combined with Razor templates